# CSS - placeholder text differs even if properties are same

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have search input beside navigation toggler. I want to style the text of placeholder as navigation toggler's heading but they are not similar even if the properties are same.

See:

[image: Look of the behaviour]

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:#B2B4B5;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color:#B2B4B5;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    color:#B2B4B5;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color:#B2B4B5;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}
#menu-toggler > h4 {
    width:auto;
    padding:0 0 0 40px;
    height:25px;
    color:#B2B4B5;
}
```

Why ? Is it a bug? I am using Mozilla FF.

Comment: have you tried it on Chrome, or Opera? Maybe even IE and/or Safari?

Comment: In case my answer didn't solve your problem, could you give an example or fiddle of your code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for help but I have used alternative.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's going on but these might help you:

IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx

Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-placeholder?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3A-moz-placeholder

CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Answer (score 0):

There maybe other proprety on your CSS file that overrides the one you set, like if the text is labeled as

and you have set properties for that

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that FF requires you to be very specific with styling placeholders.

Instead of

```
:-moz-placeholder
```

try

```
input:-moz-placeholder
```

as class names (for example). Same counts for the ::-moz-placeholder styling.
Be as specific as possible, since FF tends to overwrite the placeholder if it has a more specific styling on the element.